# Plugin in Java for Monitoring VIrtual machines running on Libvirt

Tags: java, swing, graph, libvirt

I need a plugin to monitor the following:

1. CPU, network and disk statistics
2. Virtual machines CPU based on [libvirt](http://libvirt.org/)
3. Generate graphs for both above options
4. Open remote connection to other machines and do the same.

on my SWING based application. All the plugins I've tried out(Munin and nagios) only produce graphs on a browser widow, which isn't what I want.

I've found a  manual way to do it where all the data is sent over sockets to the graph drawing PC where I use JFreechart to draw the charts. Is there a plugin to do all this(or atleast some of this)? Or should I migrate this question to another specific forum?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a look at [`JavaSysMon`](https://github.com/jezhumble/javasysmon), which is "designed to provide an OS-independent way to manage OS processes and get live system performance information such as CPU and memory usage."

Comment: @trashgod- Thanks but is there a specific plugin for monitoring virtual machine information?(libvirt)

Comment: I didn't see anything specific, but the framework might limit the effort required to support [`libvirt`](http://libvirt.org/).